# DELETE MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a query which generates a result:

```
SELECT urenID FROM uren WHERE uren.urenDossierID IN (SELECT dossierID FROM dossier WHERE dossierKlantID NOT IN (SELECT klantID from klant))
```

Now I want to delete all the records which generates that query. Now is my question; how to do that?

Comment: Are all elements to delete located in uren table or you want delete also data from dossier and klantID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `SELECT urenID` by `DELETE`

```
DELETE FROM uren WHERE uren.urenDossierID IN (SELECT dossierID FROM dossier WHERE dossierKlantID NOT IN (SELECT klantID from klant))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DELETE FROM uren WHERE urenID in (
   SELECT urenID FROM uren WHERE uren.urenDossierID IN (SELECT dossierID FROM dossier WHERE dossierKlantID NOT IN (SELECT klantID from klant)))
```

Comment: Then I am getting this error;
    [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'uren' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

I'm a strong believer that `JOIN` is faster than `IN`

```
DELETE  a
FROM    uren a
        LEFT JOIN dossier b
            ON a.urenDossierID = b.dossierID
        LEFT JOIN klant c
            ON b.dossierKlantID = c.klantID
WHERE   b.dossierID IS NOT NULL AND
        c.klantID IS NULL
```

Comment: @ypercube if i use `INNER JOIN dossier b
            ON a.urenDossierID = b.dossierID`, all the records of `uren` will all be deleted if it has no match on `dossier`.